# node cluster.isPrimary is undefined

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing, child-process, node-cluster

Node says that `cluster.isMaster` is deprecated and we should use `cluster.isPrimary`. But, while `isMaster` is returning me true without problem, I getting `undefined` when I try `cluster.isPrimary`:

```
const cluster = require("cluster");

console.log(cluster.isPrimary); /// undefined

console.log(cluster.isMaster); /// true
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are on at least Node version 16.0.0

you can see this by running this command in your terminal:

```
node --version
```

Comment: i'm in the current LTS, version 14.18.1

Comment: as per node documentation isPrimary was added in version 16.0.0 of nodejs. You should update your node version to the latest release to use that functionality.

isPrimary docs: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_isprimary

nodejs download: https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 5):

Use node v16+ and add `"esModuleInterop": true` into `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

In Node 18, I imported the module as suggested in [an example](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#clusterworker) from the official docs:

```
import cluster from 'node:cluster';
```

I do have Typescript 4.2, and I do have the `"esModuleInterop": true` flag set in `tsconfig.json` and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used this statement and with node v19 and works for me:

```
import cluster, { Worker } from 'cluster'
```